# How to produce Avro message in kafka topic from apache nifi and then read it using kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-nifi

I want to produce some generic data into kafka topic using apache nifi and i want this data to be in avro format. 
What i've done for it:

1. Create new schema in schema registry:

> {   "type": "record",   "name": "my_schema",   "namespace":
>   "my_namespace",   "doc": "",   "fields": [
>       {
>         "name": "key",
>         "type": "int"
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "value",
>         "type": [
>           "null",
>           "int"
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         "name": "event_time",
>         "type": "long"
>       }   ] }

2. Create simple nifi pipeline:
   [image]
   ConvertAvroSchema settings:
   [image]
   PublishKafkaRecord settings:
   [image]
   AvroReader settings:
   [image]
   AvroRecordSetWriter settings:
   [image]
3. Then i try to read it using kafka streams:

   public class Test {
       private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(KafkaFilterUsingCacheAvro.class);

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Properties properties = new Properties();

       properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker:9092");
       properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "app");
       properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
       properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
       properties.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "registry:8081");

       StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
       KStream<String, GenericRecord> source = builder.stream("topic");
       source.foreach((k, v) -> logger.info(String.format("[%s]: %s", k, v.toString())));

       Topology topology = builder.build();
       KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, properties);
       streams.start();
   }
   ```

   }

GenericAvroSerde - https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/kafka-streams/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/utils/GenericAvroSerde.java

And in result i get errors:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException:
>   Error deserializing Avro message for id -1 Caused by:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic
>   byte!

I also tried to explicitly set avro schema in avroreader\writer but it didn't help. Also, if i try to simply read bytes from topic and convert it into a string representation, i get something like this:

> Objavro.schema{"type":"record","name":"my_schema","namespace":"my_namespace","doc":"","fields":[{"name":"key","type":"int"},{"name":"value","type":["null","int"]},{"name":"event_time","type":"long"}]}avro.codecsnappyÛ4ým[©q
>   ÃàG0 ê¸ä»/}½{Û4ým[©q ÃàG0

How can i fix it?

Comment: I don't think you need to download that example serde class... There's already one provided by Confluent, and Avro isn't meant to be human readable, so there's nothing to "fix" in your string represented data.

Comment: In any case, if you're using ExecuteSQL, have you looked at Kafka Connect JDBC? Which natively integrates with Avro and Confluent Schema Registry?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, i've looked at kafka connect, but ExecuteSQL is just for generating some random data for testing.
 In the end of pipeline i want to use kafka connect to store transformed data into DB.

Comment: Nifi can store data as well. As far as random data goes, KSQL project includes a utility called "datagen"

Comment: Hm, i'll look at KSQL datagen. Didn't consider it before for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the PublishKafka processor your Avro writer is configured with "Schema Write Strategy" of "Embedded Avro Schema". This means the messages being written to Kafka are standard Avro messages with the full schema embedded.

On your consumer side (Kafka streams) it looks like it is expecting to use the confluent schema registry, in which case it is not expecting an embedded Avro schema, it is expecting a special sequence of bytes specifying a schema id, followed by the bare Avro message.

Assuming you want to keep your consumer as is, then on the NiFi side you will want to change your Avro writer's "Schema Write Strategy" to "Confluent Schema Registry Reference". I think this might also require you to change the Avro reader to access the schema using a Confluent Schema Registry service.

Alternatively, maybe there is a way to make Kafka Streams read an embedded schema and not use the Confluent schema registry, but I have not used Kafka Streams before so I can't say if that is possible.

Comment: You would need to write a custom KStream Serde class to handle embedded schemas, but the path of least changes here would indeed be to edit Nifi to use the Confluent registry if that's what KStreams is expecting

Comment: Finaly, it worked. I changed the AvroWriter strategy as you recommended and setup a confluent schema registry service in nifi.

Comment: @NickRyan can you please share - how did you specified Schema ID in NiFi? I've changed  "Schema Write Strategy" to "Confluent Schema Registry Reference", but unable to find where to set schema id.

Comment: @deeplay, the field for schema id is "schema version" (controller service - AvroRecordWriter). I'll check this more precisely tomorrow at work

Comment: Are you sure? I think schema version is the version of schema defined in Schema Registry... on every schema update Schema Registry increases version (+1). This setting ("Schema version") sets which version of schema you want to use.